# How do we get HTML report for tests executed using Jest?

Tags: jestjs

After test execution, I am getting the result in console. Now I need  the same result in HTML format. How do we get test result in HTML report format?

Comment: What have you tried so far? You can set [reporters](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#reporters-arraymodulename--modulename-options), maybe look on NPM for ones that fit your needs

Comment: If you are getting the results in console, most probably a folder has also been created with the coverage output. Have you checked if you have the HTML report in `coverage/lcov-report` directory?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `jest-html-reporter`:

```
{
  "name": "api_ts_tests",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "tsc"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.3",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "jest": "^29.6.2",
    "jest-html-reporter": "^3.10.2",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.1",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@actions/core": "^1.10.1",
    "@actions/github": "^5.1.1",
    "js-yaml": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.ts$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "testMatch": [
      "**/?(*.)+(spec|test).[t]s?(x)"
    ],
    "reporters": [
      "default",
      [
        "./node_modules/jest-html-reporter",
        {
          "pageTitle": "Test Report"
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

The list of parameters to tune html report -> https://github.com/Hargne/jest-html-reporter/wiki/configuration#list-of-configuration-options